# beautiful soup and frames, iframes extract

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am trying to learn python and BS4, and I am trying to extract some `frames` and `iframes` from pages using BS4 like so:

```
#...snip...
soup_f = soup("frame")
if soup_f is not None:
    for frame in soup_f:
        try:
            t_iFrames_src.append(force_text(soup.frame.extract().get("src"), encoding='utf-8', strings_only=False, errors='strict'))
        except (AttributeError, UnicodeEncodeError):
            pass
        try:
            t_full_frame.append(force_text(soup.frame.extract(), encoding='utf-8', strings_only=False, errors='strict'))
        except (AttributeError, UnicodeEncodeError):
            pass
else:
    pass
```

The problem is, when the first `try..except` runs, it gets me valid results (by filling `t_iFrames_src`), but for some weird reason, the second `try...except` does not give me any results. i.e `t_full_frame` is empty

So, when I flip them around like so:

```
#...snip...
soup_f = soup("frame")
if soup_f is not None:
    for frame in soup_f:
        try:
            t_full_frame.append(force_text(soup.frame.extract(), encoding='utf-8', strings_only=False, errors='strict'))
        except (AttributeError, UnicodeEncodeError):
            pass
        try:
            t_iFrames_src.append(force_text(soup.frame.extract().get("src"), encoding='utf-8', strings_only=False, errors='strict'))
        except (AttributeError, UnicodeEncodeError):
            pass
else:
    pass
```

Now, `t_full_frame` has results but `t_iFrames_src` is empty.. I am baffled as to why this is so :(

Probably it is something VERY stupid, but Iam not able to figure out what is wrong!
Would really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `soup.tag.extract()`, BeautifulSoup *removes* and returns the first instance of `tag` from the soup. Observe the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('''
<frame src='foo'>Spam</frame>
<frame src='bar'>Eggs</frame>
''')
print(soup)

soup.frame.extract()
print(soup)
```

This gives the following output:

```
<frame src="foo">Spam</frame>
<frame src="bar">Eggs</frame>


<frame src="bar">Eggs</frame>
```

I'm guessing this isn't the behavior you want - the first `try` block is kicking the `frame` out of the soup, and so it isn't available to the second `try` block. You probably want to keep the soup intact, in which case, you shouldn't use `.extract()`. Replace your calls to `soup.frame.extract()` with just references to `frame` (the variable in your `for` loop).

That is, change these lines:

```
t_iFrames_src.append(force_text(soup.frame.extract().get("src"), encoding='utf-8', strings_only=False, errors='strict'))
t_full_frame.append(force_text(soup.frame.extract(), encoding='utf-8', strings_only=False, errors='strict'))
```

to these lines:

```
t_iFrames_src.append(force_text(frame.get("src"), encoding='utf-8', strings_only=False, errors='strict'))
                                ^^^^^
t_full_frame.append(force_text(frame, encoding='utf-8', strings_only=False, errors='strict'))
                               ^^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you VERY much for this answer senshin. I was baffled for around 3 hours trying to figure WTF was going on. Still not sure why extract would throw the elements out of the list. Weird. Anyways, your solution works perfectly. Have accepted your answer! Thanks again for all your help mate - you saved me a lot of time!

Comment: @JohnJ Glad I could help. It might be worth taking a look at the [BeautifulSoup docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract) if you run across any other methods that appear to be misbehaving.